# elasticsearch user dictionary

Tags: elasticsearch, kuromoji

I want to use the symbol '#' as a user dictionary with elasticsearch
However, setting the character "C #" in the user dictionary results in an error
ES version 5.6
I am using the Kuromoji plugin

user dictionary

```
C#,C#,シーシャープ,カスタム名詞
```

error

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary$1.compare(UserDictionary.java:94) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary$1.compare(UserDictionary.java:91) ~[?:?]
at java.util.TimSort.binarySort(TimSort.java:296) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.TimSort.sort(TimSort.java:221) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1512) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.ArrayList.sort(ArrayList.java:1462) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:175) ~[?:1.8.0_171]
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary.<init>(UserDictionary.java:91) ~[?:?]
at org.apache.lucene.analysis.ja.dict.UserDictionary.open(UserDictionary.java:81) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.KuromojiTokenizerFactory.getUserDictionary(KuromojiTokenizerFactory.java:65) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.KuromojiTokenizerFactory.<init>(KuromojiTokenizerFactory.java:52) ~[?:?]
at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry.buildMapping(AnalysisRegistry.java:342) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry.buildTokenizerFactories(AnalysisRegistry.java:176) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AnalysisRegistry.build(AnalysisRegistry.java:154) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexService.<init>(IndexService.java:145) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.index.IndexModule.newIndexService(IndexModule.java:363) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndexService(IndicesService.java:448) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.indices.IndicesService.createIndex(IndicesService.java:413) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.metadata.MetaDataCreateIndexService$1.execute(MetaDataCreateIndexService.java:378) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.ClusterStateUpdateTask.execute(ClusterStateUpdateTask.java:45) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.executeTasks(ClusterService.java:634) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.calculateTaskOutputs(ClusterService.java:612) ~[elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService.runTasks(ClusterService.java:571) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.ClusterService$ClusterServiceTaskBatcher.run(ClusterService.java:263) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher.runIfNotProcessed(TaskBatcher.java:150) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.cluster.service.TaskBatcher$BatchedTask.run(TaskBatcher.java:188) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:575) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.runAndClean(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:247) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor$TieBreakingPrioritizedRunnable.run(PrioritizedEsThreadPoolExecutor.java:210) [elasticsearch-5.6.10.jar:5.6.10]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_171]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_171]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_171]
```

Comment: can you add your mapping, sample doc and add the steps to reproduce your issue

Comment: Nobody can help you if you don't provide more details